# p5.js createCanvas no longer rendering. ngOnInit const not being accessed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, p5.js

My code used to work to render the canvas but now it doesn't. Main problem seems to be that I'm never accessing the sketch const.

I had a decent little project up and running this morning but deleted it before I pushed without realizing it.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import * as p5 from 'p5';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-sketch',
      templateUrl: './sketch.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./sketch.component.css']
    })
    export class SketchComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
        const sketch = (s) => {
          debugger;
          s.preload = () => {
          }
          s.setup = () => {
           s.createCanvas(400,400);
          };
          s.draw = () => {
             s.background(51);
          };
        }
      }
    }
```

This should render a canvas 400x400, but instead, it does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to invoke p5 in ngOnInit:

```
 p5 : any;
 ngOnInit() {
  const sketch = (s) => {
      debugger;
      s.preload = () => {
      }
      s.setup = () => {
       s.createCanvas(400,400);
      };
      s.draw = () => {
         s.background(51);
      };
    }
  this.p5 = new p5(sketch);
}
```